# Storing Sqlite DB in RoamingFolder

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a data tracker app and I would like to be able to sync user data across both the phone and the windows store application. Does anyone have any experience with using the Roaming Folder to store a Sqlite Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoamingFolder limit 100kb.
if you want to sync your setting, try save file as json or xml, better than sqlite.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to find any MSDN documentation about the storage limits. That's a bit too small for what I was looking to store.

Comment: The documentation is vague with "The sync engine may limit the total size of settings and files that can roam". I'm guessing that may up the limit in the future.

Comment: You can query the limit via [`RoamingStorageQuota`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingstoragequota.aspx)